# R: Use active binding in object generator to conditionally add new class to R6 objects

Tags: r, oop, inheritance, r6

I have a simple R6 object generator:

```
thing <- R6Class("youngThing",
                 private = list(
                   ..age = 0),
                 active = list(
                   age = function(){
                     private$..age <- private$..age + 1
                     private$..age
                   }
                 )
)
```

That gives me a simple R6 object, where `..age` increases by 1 every time the active `age` field is called:

```
a_thing <- thing$new()

a_thing$age
# [1] 1
```

I want the object class of a_thing to change given a threshold value of the private field `..age`, like this:

```
class(a_thing)
# [1] "youngThing" "R6"

for(timestep in 1:10){
  if(a_thing$age >5 & ! inherits(a_thing, "olderThing")){
    class(a_thing) <- c("olderThing", class(a_thing))
  }
}

class(a_thing)
# [1] "olderThing" "youngThing" "R6"
```

However, I want this to happen within the object. Is there a way to include this as an active binding in the object generator, so that any object created from it will have this functionality built-in?

NB. It is preferred that the threshold class is added to the object; that it does not replace the existing classes.

Comment: Changing class seems like a bit of an odd design choice. Why not just have a public `is_old` Boolean flag that can be interrogated as required?

Comment: I expect there to be some answers that make this possible technically, but think twice about what this means from a design perspective. What if you assign an object to a variable, then call the method so the class changes, then call a function that expects the old class with the object. 

This breaks some assumptions usually made about the (immutable) class of an object and could lead to problems later on.

Comment: @AllanCameron Hi, thanks for the comment. In a situation where one object is one individual, I can use an S3 generic method to implement a different method depending on the class (age) of the object (individual).

Comment: @jayb or you could have a single method that checks the age field and behaves accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the class of `self`.

```
library(R6)

thing <- R6Class(
  "youngThing",
  private = list(..age = 0),
  active = list(
    age = function() {
      private$..age <- private$..age + 1

      if(private$..age > 5 && !inherits(self, "olderThing")){
        class(self) <- c("olderThing", class(self))
      }
      private$..age
    }
  )
)
```

`a_thing` has it's original class while `age <= 5`.

```
a_thing <- thing$new()

a_thing$age; a_thing$age; a_thing$age; a_thing$age; a_thing$age
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 4
#> [1] 5

class(a_thing)
#> [1] "youngThing" "R6"
```

Then it updates once it goes over `5`.

```
a_thing$age
#> [1] 6

class(a_thing)
#> [1] "olderThing" "youngThing" "R6"
```